# Sharepoint Online adding a list item using client object model

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013

I have used Javascript and sharepoint client object model to add a list item to a list. I am working with a sharepoint 2013 online public site. I have a content editor with the following javascript code.

```
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

  var web = clientContext.get_web();

  var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Subscriptions');

  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;   

  // Create a new list item 
  var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation(); 
  var listItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);           

  listItem.set_item('Title',email );

  listItem.update();
```

This code works fine for the user who has permission. it will add a element to the subscription list. But it fails when we use this for a Anonymous user. After searching I found that that there is a tool : http://anonymous365.codeplex.com/.

But it did not work from the code though i gave anonymous access to the list.

Please suggest me a way to overcome this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Access to SharePoint Online requires an authenticated session of some variety.  The only site that is available for public (anonymous) access is the pre-provisioned "public site" that is available with certain subscriptions which is meant to host a standard corporate website.  A sample project that shows how to support claims authentication with SPO can be found here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Remote-Authentication-in-b7b6f43c/

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Seems like I cannot achive this only by Javacript. We need to have Managed client object model with c#.